# Get results from multiple deferred and pass to function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, deferred

I have a function like this to process some array of data:

```
function ProcessItems(data){
    var def = $.Deferred();
    var results = [];   
    $.each(data, function(v, k)
    {
        // GetItem(k) returns promise
        results.push(GetItem(k));
    });
    return $.when.apply(null, results);
}
```

where i'm trying to get some items with GetItem(k) function and then i want to return selected data and pass it to function like this:

```
// data -> JSON array, results -> array of promises
ProcessItems(data).then( function(results) { return ShowItems(results); } )
```

and display it using following function:

```
function ShowItems(items) {
    // here items have no data, but only a promise objects
    var def = $.Deferred();
    $.each(items, function(v, k)
    {
        alert(k);
    });
    def.resolve();
    return def.promise();
}
```

I know that i can get my data from arguments here

```
$.when.apply(null, results).then(function() {
    // arguments[0] etc <= data is here
});
```

But how to pass it to the next function?

Comment: Btw, there's no reason that `ShowItems` would need to return a promise that is fulfilled with `undefined`, and you can omit that function expression and simply do `ProcessItems(data).then(ShowItems)`

Comment: Thanks, pal. Now I get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know, jQuery's `$.when()` is awkward in that it delivers its data in the form of an arguments list, not an array. So all you need to know is how to convert `arguments` to a proper array.

The trick is `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)`, or `[].slice.call(arguments)` if you like.

In full :

```
function ProcessItems(data) {
    var results = $.map(data, function(value, key) {
        return GetItem(key);// or GetItem(value) ?
    });
    return $.when.apply(null, results).then(function() {
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);//convert arguments list to array
    });
}

function ShowItems(items) {
    //items is an array
    items.forEach(function(value, index) {
        alert(value);
    });
}

ProcessItems(data).then(ShowItems);
```

Comment: Thank you! You are the best!